# Selecting only nth-child of a certain element type

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a several forms, and I'd like to select only the first and second input box of each form

```
$("form input:nth-child(1), form input:nth-child(2)");
```

But this doesn't work because each input has a label next to it, so there is no input that is `nth-child(1)`.

Example at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ayiqo3/edit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/), like this:

```
$("form input:lt(2)");
```

This selects all elements that match at less-than the passed index, the first and second elements are index 0 and 1, and will match this selector :)

Comment: wohoo! one selector instead of two! sweeet (:

Answer (score 3):

You can use `eq()`:

```
$("form input:eq(0), form input:eq(1)");
```

This selects the first and second of the **matched** elements.

Comment: At first I thought there was something wrong with `eq`, but then I discovered that it's zero-based... thanks, though (:

Comment: @peirix: Yes, if you are acting on the array of *matched* elements, the index is zero based. If you deal with functions that act on the DOM nodes, it is normally one-based.

Comment: This is because `:eq` is a non-standard jQuery selector based on the jQuery `eq()` method, which is 0-based. The same is true of `lt`. `nth-child` is a native CSS selector; the CSS standard has taken the very regrettable policy of all indexes being 1-based.